# What is the purpose of Light and Dark Tone?

Tags: microscope

Every time card:

- Period
- Event
- Scene

Is to be marked with a Black (/filled) or White (/unfilled) circle,
to indicate if the events described with in are Light or Dark, in nature/theme.
Periods and Events are marked when created, scenes are marked at the end of them being played out.

For example, the Event of "The Rebels attack, and destroy the Capital", could be a Light event, if they are the good rebels, freeing the people from the dark empire. Or it could be a dark event if they are ruining the peaceful kingdom.

I understand how to decide on the Tone (Light/Dark),
but not on what effect these have in game.

I see that they clarify the descriptions on the cards a bit.
But do they have a mechanical effect?

I have read through the "How to Play" section in full, but not the appendix on "How/Why Microscope works". I've only flicked through that.

Is there some mechanic i missed, like:

- "Within a Dark Period, No more than 50% of the Events at any given time can be Light?"
- Or "At the end of play count up how many Light/Dark events you have. This is interesting to track as time goes by to learn more about the your preferred playstyle"